# Check if char is nil objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I have a char but when I run a check to see if it is nil, I get an exception `Comparison between pointer and integer`. This is my code:

```
char *character1 = 'B';
if (character1 != nil){
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

This is in objective c.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Characters are (usually) 8-bit integer values, while `nil` is a pointer. Perhaps you want the NUL character, `'\0'`:

```
if (character1 != '\0') {
```

Notice the *single* quotes around the value mean it is of `char` type.

Comment: Does this work in objective c and when assigning a value to the character1 do I have to use '\0' instead of null or nill?

Comment: Yes, this part of Objective-C is the same as in C. You should use `'\0'` when assigning to a `char` value.